# React - How can I access a state/array that's in one .js file in a different .js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

```
export default class Board extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { board: ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']};
    this.counter = 0;
    this.limit = 0;
}
```

I want to access the board with these question marks (this.state) in a different js file, such as...

```
import Board from './Board';

export default class Interface extends React.Component
{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

resetBoard()
{
    Board.state.setState({ board: ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']});
}

render()
{
    return(
        <header id="game-reset">
            <h1 onClick={this.resetBoard}>Reset</h1>
        </header>
    );
}
}
```

Sorry for the ugly formatting issues, but essentially I'm trying to reset the board from Board.js back to all question marks using the resetBoard() function in Interface.js
The problem is, I need to access the "this.state" board from Board.js. I know the line

> Board.state.setState({ board: ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']});

doesn't work, because I'm not fully understanding what syntax is necessary to access that array. How could I access that first array such that I can alter it back to all question marks? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the state of another component is not possible in React. And even if there is a way - it's not recommended.

There are two options to resolve your issue:

1. You can keep your state in a component that is a parent to both your components, and pass it (along with the necessary functions) as props down to the other components.
2. You can use a state management library like Redux or MobX. I would recommend MobX because of its simplicity, but you should check both out and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As Mat mentioned in his earlier comment the `state` of Component belongs to itself. A component can pass it's state to it's children via `props`.

The way to update the state of parent is you define the function in the parent component and pass it also as `props` to the child.

So in your example it will be something like:

**Board.js**

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { board: ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']};
    this.counter = 0;
    this.limit = 0;

    this.handleResetBoard = this.handleResetBoard.bind(this);
  }


  handleResetBoard() {
    this.setState({
      board: ['y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Interface</h2>
        <Interface board={this.state.board} resetBoard={this.handleResetBoard} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Interface.js**

```
import Board from './Board';

class Interface extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <header>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.board, null, 2)}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.props.resetBoard}>Button</button>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

see this in action: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3uqaox0/)

I would also encourage you to read more about where to keep state here: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live